# How to use setRGB method with float or double parameters?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I have a method that returns a double value and I want to set the corresponding x,y pixel with that returned value.

But `setRGB()` and `Color()` only takes `int` parameters.

How to achieve that?

```
double enh = enhance(r, g, b);
Color gcolor = new Color(enh, enh, enh, a);
img.setRGB(x, y, gcolor.getRGB());
```

Comment: What is the range of the double values? E.G. if it is 0 - 1, multiply them by 255 and cast to an int value.

Comment: Thank you it works great, but could you pls explain that to me as i am new to image processing?

Comment: Less to do with images or image processing and more to do with colors. Read the documentation for [`Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) for a better understanding.